# Why does my wifi iPad think its location is in another state?

Tags: ipad, geolocation

I live in MA but my iPad thinks it is in Clarksville, Indiana (both in Maps and other apps). This becomes annoying if I try to post in Facebook and all friends ask what I am doing in IN. This has been happening in both iOS 5 and 6.

I've read on the web where people claim this is because of the Apple location database thinks my wireless router is in IN but if I post a comment to Facebook on my wife's iMac (also on wifi) it correctly identifies my location.

I've also used my iPhone to determine my location while connected to my wifi which is supposed to update the Apple location database but it's had no effect.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Which version of the iPad do you have? Wifi only, Wifi +3G?  Gen 1 (iPad), 2 (iPad 2) or 3 (new iPad)?

Comment: We actually have two that show the same behavior a iPad 2 and an iPad 3 both wifi only.

Comment: Using the IP address of your home internet connection (the internet facing IP address), I'd be interested to see what the response to a geolocation request would be, as it may actually return the location of your ISP rather than you - try here and see what the response is http://www.ipligence.com/geolocation

Comment: Checked this on our two iPads, PC and Mac:
IPligence thinks we are in New York
Facebook and http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup - correctly puts us in Weymouth, MA
Only the location service on the iPads think we are in Clarksville IN.

Comment: And I have a friend who just moved back from India and her iPad thinks it is in Moscow (both now and before the move).

Answer (score 2):

The iPad location service now reports the correct location just seems to have taken a really long time to update.

Steps:

- Connect iPhone to the wifi network
- Open Maps and click on location arrow
- Wait for Apple location db to update